# Remove selection element from html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, pagination

Hey am new to Javascript and am working on a quote website. I have a website which is a quote website example. To understand the question let see the CodePen.

***The CodePen***
https://codepen.io/Akash11166666/pen/JjRzqzp

As saw in my CodePen there were some quotes and a copy buttons bellow them. Just see at the bottom of the page you can a selection which decides how many quotes do you want in a page.

***Now my problem is that selection which is located in the bottom of the page. I don't need the selection. I can solve it by removing all the other options. But I need it to be clean from root. I tried to remove the whole html of selection but it destroys the Javascript and none of the other functions work.***

What I need is, can we remove the selection from html and it's function from Javascript and make the quotes limited to 16 in per page.

I have asked with my friends but none of them got it. As am new to Javascript am not aware about this issues.

I thank in advance for those who answer this question.

For reference my CodePen project
***Html***

```
  <div class="mainStatus">
   <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
<div class="allquotes"></div>
<div class="pagable-status">
  <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
  <div class="pagable-actions">
    <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
    <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
    <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
    <select name="page-size">
      <option>5</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
</div>
```

***Css***

```
/* Main Status */
.hidden {

  display:none;

}
.mainStatus{
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 max-width: 95%;
 width: 95%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.statusHeading{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #18b495;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.latestatus{
 display: grid;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 width: 445px;
 min-height: 130px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.allStatus{
 display: flex;
}
.latestatus p{
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
}
.copystatus{
 font-weight: 500;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
}
.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}
.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #18b495;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 30px;
}
.btn:hover {
 transform: scale(0.98);
}
.status-copy-alert {

 position: relative;

 background-color: #18b495;

 color: #ffffff;

 padding: 10px 10px;

 border-radius: 5px;

 left: 8px;

 text-transform: uppercase;

 letter-spacing: 0.05em;

 font-weight: 500;

 visibility: visible;

}

.status-copy-alert:before{

 content:"";

 position: absolute;

 height: 10px;

 width: 10px;

 background-color: #18b495;

 left: -5px;

 transform: rotate(45deg);

 top: 39%;

}
```

***Javascript***

```
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button><span class="status-copy-alert hidden" id="status-copy-alert">Copied</span>
</div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

  return[{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
]; 
}
document.querySelector('.allquotes').addEventListener(

  'click',

  function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    

    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.copystatus')) {

        const quote = e.target.parentNode.closest('.latestatus')

            .childNodes[0].textContent;
      
      const notify = e.target.nextSibling.closest('.status-copy-alert');
      
      notify.classList.toggle('hidden');
      setTimeout(() => {
  notify.classList.add('hidden');
}, 600);

        const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');

        textArea.value = quote;

        document.body.appendChild(textArea);

        textArea.select();

        document.execCommand('Copy');

        textArea.remove();

    }

  },

  false

);
main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be more to it (some event listeners need to be removed), but fundamentally just change

```
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
```

to

```
const getPageSize = () => 16;
```

Comment: I have replaced it to 16 but how can remove the element from html because if I remove the selection element from html the Javascript get destroyed.

Comment: Delete the select element.  There is some javascript code that attempts to set an event listener, remove that too (pageSize.addEventListener...).